# Do the rank emblems from other CoD games in Modern Warfare 3 still update regularly?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

The emblems under a player card in Modern Warfare 3 have 4 placements of which hold your rank in the other four recent Call of Duty games:

- Modern Warfare 1
- World at War
- Modern Warfare 2
- Black Ops

I've played all four games, and all my ranks correspond with the rank that I was in when I last played them. I played Modern Warfare 2 not so long ago and it changed accordingly.

However, last night and this morning I played Black Ops and Modern Warfare 1, ranked a little and it didn't propagate the change to Modern Warfare 3.

Is this feature turned off now? Or does it take awhile to update in the system to recognize any change?

Answer (score 1):

From the OP (originally posted as a comment):

> I [have] seen the change on there today so I guess that this takes a few hours to collect the info and show it on MW3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how the system works. The multiplayer rank you obtain is only for that particular game. Levels achieved in Black Ops will only affect that game, et cetera.

Comment: No the emblems under my player card on mw3 have 4 placements of which hold your rank in the other four games... MW1, WAW, MW2, and BO. I had seen the change on there today so I guess that this takes a few hours to collect the info and show it on MW3.